# Why this trigger doesn't compile(oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Error: SQL Statement ignored (underline UPDATE TABLE)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CANCEL_TICKET
  AFTER INSERT ON CANCEL
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE TICKET
      SET TICKET.TICKET_ID := NULL
      WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID;
  END;
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for **TABLE** and a colon **:** is more in your statement, so better

```
UPDATE TICKET
SET TICKET.TICKET_ID = NULL
```

Comment: try without **TABLE**

Comment: @user3238724 - you've stumbled across one of the differences between PL/SQL, which is Oracle's procedural extensions to SQL, and SQL itself. You're correct that in PL/SQL `=` is used for comparison and `:=` is used for assignment. In SQL, however, `=` is used for both assignment and comparison. And an `UPDATE` statement is always SQL, even if it appears in the middle of a PL/SQL program. Share and enjoy.